# Execute recursive saves together or seperately?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

I have a complex graph of objects that I am saving to the database. These objects can each connect to other graphs of a similar type. I wish to save the graph of objects and all of the graphs they connect to recursively.

Is it bad practice to aggregate all of the saves and execute them under one transaction? Should each graph be saved seperately?

Currently I save each subgraph separately. Below is example code (.NET)

```cs
public async Task<GraphObj> SaveAllGraphs(GraphObj graph)
{
    foreach (var node in graph.nodes)
    {
        if (node.subGraph != null)
        {
            await SaveGraph(node.subGraph);
        }
    }
    return await SaveGraphInstance(graph);
}
```

```cs
async public Task SaveGraphInstance(GraphObj graph)
{
        var txClient = (ITransactionalGraphClient)_client;
        await txClient.ConnectAsync();

        using (var tx = txClient.BeginTransaction())
        {
            await _client.Cypher.Create(...).ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
            await _client.Cypher.Create(...).ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to answer as it's dependent on your use case.

*If* your subgraphs etc should all be there, or not at all, then you should do it all in one transaction. This is no different to anything else - database or indeed application wise. The benefit of the transaction is that is any one part of it fails, it all fails.

In terms of performance, there's no real difference between the two approaches, in both you are making *n* calls to the DB.